# ionic : Unable to resolve host no address associated with hostname

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this error :unable to resolve host no address associated with hostname … I found issue when I add 
in AndroidManifest.xml but this exist in AndroidManifest.xml … how to resolve this error please please

code AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.ionic.starter" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
        <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
            <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
                <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
                <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
            </provider>
            <activity android:label="@string/multi_app_name" android:name="com.synconset.MultiImageChooserActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
        </application>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    </manifest>
```

Comment: any help please

Comment: Base on my exp may be your device is not connected with internet ? did you check that ?

Comment: what I am asking is your device or emulator is connected with wifi or network ?

Comment: @CodeChanger with wifi

Comment: @CodeChanger any help please!